# Magento 2 Account dashboard was messed up after installing magento2-category-sidebar

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a problem with my account dashboard. I noticed lately after I installed the Sebwite magento2-category-sidebar extension in the site. If you have ideas please help me.

Here is the sample screenshot:
[image]

Thanks,
MazeStricks

Comment: Post link of your used extension. Or is it :https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar?

Also look at it: Here is solution of that extension: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40603684/949003

Comment: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar <---yes this one. Thanks bro I'll try that solution you provided.

Comment: Still no luck bro. I tried that code. It did not solve my current problem.

Comment: Ok. I havnt tried this extension . will check in evening and let you know. If issue in extension then you can also report in github.

Comment: Thanks Jai. I'll try it also in my end. and let's compare experience about the output. I'll try to install fresh copy of magento 2.

Comment: If possible then go for magento 2.1.3

Comment: I'm currently using that magento package 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I manage to fix the problem by my own way.
The problem is when you use this extension Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar in your site. Your account dashboard will be replaced and messed up.

Here's what the result looks like after installing this module to your site.

[image]

So in order to fix the problem account dashboard was messed up.

Here's what i did to my site.

1. go to that extension under: m2test/app/code/Sebwite/Sidebar/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

   - as you can see in that screenshot of the file 2columns-left.xml. I added **"custom"** in the container name. the default of that is **"div.sidebar.main"** and now it looks like this: **"div.sidebar.main.custom"**.

[image]

and now pooff! here's the result of that code. My account dashboard is now back to normal. you might wonder why the look of my account dashboard is different from the the account dashboard in the first screenshot. That's because I created a theme yesterday.

I hope this will help for the future people that will use this extension sebwite.

Thanks, 
Happy coding :)

[image]

Comment: Good to know that you fixed the issue. You can also update on github for the extension to help community.

Comment: Yes I already did that. I commented in one of the issues submitted in that github repository thanks